# Setting a property of a class when the containing class is constructed

Tags: f#

A class `Test` which upon construction creates an instance of another class and sets a property would look something like this (I suppose):

```
type Test() as this =
    let a = new A()

    do this.Init()

    member this.Init() = 
        let a.Size = 10
```

However, I get a `Block following this 'let' is unfinished. Expect an expression.`

What is the correct and preferred way of doing this?

Comment: Which line does the error refer to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to mutate the `Size` property, you'll have to use the assignment operator:

```
type Test() as this =
    let a = new A()

    do this.Init()

    member this.Init() = 
        a.Size <- 10
```

However, you can write it much more succinctly like this:

```
type Test() =
    let a = A (Size = 10)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. The C# syntax is sometimes difficult to let go.